# N00b path integral formulation question

Tags: optics, quantum-electrodynamics, reflection, refraction, path-integral

I have a question about the path integral formulation used in QED etc.

The path integral formulation implies to me that index of refraction (and reflection or anything also calculated using this formulation) are dependent on the macro geometry of the object. In the case of a refractive block of glass, the index of refraction should change based on the size of the block, and in the case of a mirror, the actual reflected image of my face would be different a 1m^2 mirror than it would be in a 10m^2 mirror... This is non-intuitive, as the phenomena is unobserved - My face looks the same in a 1m^2 mirror as it looks in a 10m^2 mirror...

Have I missed something? Or is it just that the coefficients in the integral have dropped off to such small numbers it makes no practical difference?

If that is the case, would an infinitely large mirror give a different looking reflection than a 1m^2 mirror? Would it stop reflecting or get better? The integral would be including infinitely many infinitely small terms... Would it slow light down to 0?

Comment: Can you explain how you arrived at that implication?

Comment: Basically, it's only the paths which are "close" to the classical path matter in the path integral. This is because, near the classical path, the exponent is at a local maximum/minimum, and all the tiny phases "add up" there. Away from a local maximum/minimum, the nearby phases all basically cancel each other out. So making the mirror larger has basically no effect on the probability amplitudes. Light will still basically just hit it and bounce off such that the angle of incidence equals the angle of reflection.

Comment: @probably_someone I watched some Feynman lectures and videos about refraction on YouTube...

Comment: @user1379857 Your explanation satisfies me wrt. reflection, but the way refraction was explained in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YW8KuMtVpug seems somehow incompatible with your explanation. But that is to be expected from a YouTube video, which is why I wanted some clarification.

Do you know an example of someone going through the math for this?

Comment: That explanation goes for any classical path. So the same argument would go for a beam of light passing through an transparent material. Only the paths surrounding the classical path would matter.

Comment: I do not know of someone actually "going through the calculation" in this way. The Feynman path integral in QED is actually a lot more elaborate than the picture he paints in his popular book "QED" and in his popular lectures. In particular, the whole thing with the "principle of least time" coming from the path integral was something I've never really seen demonstrated, although I'm confident he is referencing a real calculation. By the time you're taking a QFT class, however, you're not really interested in studying things like mirrors.

Comment: Yes I see that. My comment was more about the erroneous explanation in that YouTube video. Thanks for the reply! :)

Comment: To understand why mirrors reflect and why light slows down in glass, you need some understanding of the molecular makeup of these materials, band structure, etc. Feynman simplifies these things, and with good reason, it makes for a great lecture. However, something always bugged me about his presentation. You can understand why mirrors reflect and why light travels slower in glass just from classical Maxwell E&M. No quantum mechanics, or quantum field theory, is required. IMO just take his lectures at face value, but don't get hung up on the details, because a lot is being swept under the rug.